# Как привязать к локальному репозиторию другой удалённый?

Tags: git, github, git-remote

Я создал на github свой репозиторий-1 (шаблон gulp-project), не форкнул.

Теперь начинаю новый проект, и в webstorm клонирую этот репозиторий-1 с шаблоном, переименовываю его, и работаю с ним как с отдельным, но уже репозиторием-2.

Если я буду коммитить, то коммиты упадут в репозиторий-1 шаблона, а мне надо что бы в новый репозиторий-2 (рабочий).

Как в этом случае правильно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

надо изменить *url* удалённого репозитория (*remote* в терминологии *git*):

```
$ git remote set-url origin url-нового-репозитория
```

здесь подразумевается, что умолчальное имя удалённого репозитория — `origin` — вы не меняли.

[пример из github-овской документации](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/).

---

> Если я буду коммитить, то коммиты упадут в репозиторий-1

вообще-то коммитить вы будете (в любом случае) в локальный репозиторий. а вот куда будут отправляться эти коммиты при команде *push* — как раз и определяет *url* удалённого репозитория.